Issue with Looker studio and the dates
I am struggling with the dates.
I've imported a data fromm Excel, with a column date
Looker studio sees it as a date (the data has the little calendar on)
enter image description here
But at the moment that I add the date boton from looker studio, and select any date the data isn't showing anymore
enter image description here
Does anyone have any idea please ?
having the dates to get a better data vizualisation
